# Simple sql query - unable to extent temp segment error

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to run a query on Oracle server like this one (I know it doesn't make sense, but a tried to make it as simple as possible):

```
select tableA.acolumn
from A.tableA, A.tableB, C.tableC
where tableA.acolumn = tableB.acolumn and tableA.cId = tableC.id
```

`tableA` and `tableC` have like 40k records, `tableB` has about 10k.

It runs for 5 mins, then throws the error

> *ORA-01652: unable to extent temp segment.*

If I execute it without "C.tableC", it finishes in 2 seconds.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Your real query doesn't have `tableC` anywhere in the `where` clause either?

Comment: What is the point of using tableC here? Also it is better to use `Inner join` between tableA and tableB.

Comment: I edited the question with tableC in the WHERE clause, but I think it should work without that.
@Kaf Unfortunately I'm not able to use INNER JOIN for other reasons.

Comment: 0_o No. No, you are able to use an `inner join`.

Comment: Okay, maybe the word "not able" was wrong. In fact, this query is generated, without using `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Are there any indices? What does the query optimizer tell you about the execution plan for the query?

Comment: Then scrap whatever's writing the query. There's no need to be afraid of writing SQL.

Comment: It **does** make a difference if you have tableC in the where clause. If you don't you'll get a cartesian join. And that's probably why the result gets so huge. Did it change when you added tableC to the where clause (btw: this is one of the really good reasons to **not** use implicit joins - you can easily miss a join condition)

Comment: It did not make any difference, the error is the same with tableC in the where clause.

Comment: @JackManey According to the execution plan there is a `hash join` and `merge join cartesian`, then `index full scan` on tableC, and finally `table access full` on tableA and tableB. It should run in about 10 seconds, according to the plan's `Time` column

Comment: @JackManey I have no access to the generator, and I dont want to write  ~100 procedures on my own.

Comment: I can't see why my question was downvoted. Please explain it, so I can avoid the mistake next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. 
tableC needed to be analyzed manually with the gather_table_stats function.